# Converting UIImage to and from [[UIColor]]?

Tags: swift, uiimage, uicolor, unsafe-pointers

I'd like to convert my UIImage to and from a 2-dimensional UIColor array. I have only found ways to do this with `UnsafePointer<UInt8>`.

Is there a way to do this in Swift without using pointers?

Comment: Please describe your problem in more detail. Post code excerpts and show what you have already tried and what doesn't work with your attempt.